# NoBackendError while getting features of audio files using librosa

Tags: python

Im using jupyter notebook for executing this. The Whole program is available in this link https://github.com/MiteshPuthran/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer/blob/master/final_results_gender_test.ipynb
I tried using ffmpeg, tried using another .wav file, nothing seems to be working. please help.

This is the code :

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['feature'])
bookmark=0
for index,y in enumerate(mylist):
    if mylist[index][6:-16]!='01' and mylist[index][6:-16]!='07' and mylist[index][6:-16]!='08' and mylist[index][:2]!='su' and mylist[index][:1]!='n' and mylist[index][:1]!='d':
        X, sample_rate = librosa.load('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/pw-4/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/'+y, res_type='kaiser_fast',duration=2.5,sr=22050*2,offset=0.5)
        sample_rate = np.array(sample_rate)
        mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, 
                                            sr=sample_rate, 
                                            n_mfcc=13),
                        axis=0)
        feature = mfccs
        #[float(i) for i in feature]
        #feature1=feature[:135]
        df.loc[bookmark] = [feature]
        bookmark=bookmark+1
```

---

and this is the error im getting:

```
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py:155, in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    153 else:
    154     # Otherwise, create the soundfile object
--> 155     context = sf.SoundFile(path)
    157 with context as sf_desc:

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\soundfile.py:629, in SoundFile.__init__(self, file, mode, samplerate, channels, subtype, endian, format, closefd)
    627 self._info = _create_info_struct(file, mode, samplerate, channels,
    628                                  format, subtype, endian)
--> 629 self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
    630 if set(mode).issuperset('r+') and self.seekable():
    631     # Move write position to 0 (like in Python file objects)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\soundfile.py:1183, in SoundFile._open(self, file, mode_int, closefd)
   1182     raise TypeError("Invalid file: {0!r}".format(self.name))
-> 1183 _error_check(_snd.sf_error(file_ptr),
   1184              "Error opening {0!r}: ".format(self.name))
   1185 if mode_int == _snd.SFM_WRITE:
   1186     # Due to a bug in libsndfile version <= 1.0.25, frames != 0
   1187     # when opening a named pipe in SFM_WRITE mode.
   1188     # See http://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/issues/77.

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\soundfile.py:1357, in _error_check(err, prefix)
   1356 err_str = _snd.sf_error_number(err)
-> 1357 raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))

RuntimeError: Error opening 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/pw-4/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/AudioRecorder.ipynb': File contains data in an unknown format.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NoBackendError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [46], in <cell line: 3>()
      3 for index,y in enumerate(mylist):
      4     if mylist[index][6:-16]!='01' and mylist[index][6:-16]!='07' and mylist[index][6:-16]!='08' and mylist[index][:2]!='su' and mylist[index][:1]!='n' and mylist[index][:1]!='d':
----> 5         X, sample_rate = librosa.load('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/pw-4/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/'+y, res_type='kaiser_fast',duration=2.5,sr=22050*2,offset=0.5)
      6         sample_rate = np.array(sample_rate)
      7         mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=X, 
      8                                             sr=sample_rate, 
      9                                             n_mfcc=13),
     10                         axis=0)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\librosa\util\decorators.py:88, in deprecate_positional_args.<locals>._inner_deprecate_positional_args.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     86 extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     87 if extra_args <= 0:
---> 88     return f(*args, **kwargs)
     90 # extra_args > 0
     91 args_msg = [
     92     "{}={}".format(name, arg)
     93     for name, arg in zip(kwonly_args[:extra_args], args[-extra_args:])
     94 ]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py:174, in load(path, sr, mono, offset, duration, dtype, res_type)
    172 if isinstance(path, (str, pathlib.PurePath)):
    173     warnings.warn("PySoundFile failed. Trying audioread instead.", stacklevel=2)
--> 174     y, sr_native = __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
    175 else:
    176     raise (exc)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\librosa\core\audio.py:198, in __audioread_load(path, offset, duration, dtype)
    192 """Load an audio buffer using audioread.
    193 
    194 This loads one block at a time, and then concatenates the results.
    195 """
    197 y = []
--> 198 with audioread.audio_open(path) as input_file:
    199     sr_native = input_file.samplerate
    200     n_channels = input_file.channels

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\audioread\__init__.py:116, in audio_open(path, backends)
    113         pass
    115 # All backends failed!
--> 116 raise NoBackendError()

NoBackendError:
```

Comment: You are trying to open a ipynb file with librosa, that will of course not work.

Comment: To be clear, you always need to read and analyze the whole traceback, in you case you can find this: RuntimeError: Error opening 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/pw-4/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/Speech-Emotion-Analyzer-master/AudioRecorder.ipynb': File contains data in an unknown format.